# Custom Iterator removeIf does not remove element

Tags: java, iterator

I'm using a custom `Iterator` to a custom `LinkedList` structure in my project. However when iterating through the `LinkedList`, the Iterator does not remove the entry from the given list.

My custom Iterator:

```
package plotter.structures;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/**
 * 
 * @author croemheld
 *
 * @param <T> The type of the elements of the {@link LinkedList}.
 */
public class LinkedListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    /**
     * Previous element in the {@link LinkedListIterator}.
     */
    private ListNode<T> previous = null;

    /**
     * Current element in the {@link LinkedListIterator}.
     */
    private ListNode<T> current;

    private LinkedList<T> collection;

    /**
     * Returns an instance of {@link LinkedListIterator} which iterates from the head
     * to the tail of a {@link LinkedList}.
     * 
     * @param collection The collection to iterate through.
     */
    public LinkedListIterator(LinkedList<T> collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
        this.current = collection.getHead();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a {@link LinkedListIterator} which starts at a specific index.
     * 
     * @param collection The {@link LinkedList} for this {@link LinkedListIterator}.
     * @param index The index to start at.
     */
    public LinkedListIterator(LinkedList<T> collection, int index) {
        this.current = collection.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return this.current != null;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        if(!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        T element = this.current.getElement();
        this.previous = this.current;
        this.current = this.current.getNext();

        return element;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        if(this.previous.getPrev() != null) {
            this.previous.getPrev().setNext(this.previous.getNext());
        }

        this.current.setPrev(this.previous.getPrev());
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return The next element of this {@link LinkedListIterator}.
     */
    public T peek() {
        if(!hasNext()) {
            return null;
        }

        return this.current.getElement();
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the next element is null or equal to the current element.
     * 
     * @param element The element of the current iteration.
     * 
     * @return True, if the next element is equal to the current one or if the next element is null.
     */
    public boolean hasEqualFollower(T element) {
        return (peek() != null && !peek().equals(element) || peek() == null);
    }

}
```

My `LinkedList` reduced to the method that does not work properly:

```
public class LinkedList<T> implements Collection<T> {

    /**
     * The head {@link ListNode} of this {@link LinkedList}.
     */
    private ListNode<T> head;

    /**
     * The tail {@link ListNode} of this {@link LinkedList}.
     */
    private ListNode<T> tail;

    /**
     * The length of this {@link LinkedList}.
     */
    private int size;

    // [...]

    @Override
    public boolean removeIf(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
        int count = size();
        LinkedListIterator<T> iterator = new LinkedListIterator<T>(this);

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            T element = iterator.next();
            if(predicate.test(element)) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }

        return size() < count;
    }

    // [..]
}
```

The `predicate.test(element)` properly returns true for the said element, but it does not remove the element from my `LinkedList`.

The invocation looks like this:

```
result.removeIf(node -> node.getValue().equals(ComplexNumber.ZERO.toString()));
```

At this point the `equals` method compares two `String` objects with both having the value `(0.0 + 0.0i)` (complex number representation) and returns true correctly.

Why is the element still in the list after the `removeIf` invocation?

Comment: What did you discover when you debugged this?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth This is in fact pretty weird, because I could not find anything. After the invocation the removeIf steps into the `while` loop and follows the execution graph perfectly, even going into the `iterator.remove()` call. The values are correctly set afterwards so I assume i made a mistake in my general `LinkedList` implementation or I'm missing something here.

Comment: Your iterator class is incomplete.  It stores a reference to the collection being iterated in only one of its constructors. That reference is needed in `remove()` for the cases where you're removing the first or last element and need to adjust `head` or `tail`.  Usually, the iterator implementation is a private inner class of the data structure being iterated so it has access to the collection without needing to be given a reference to it.  You would benefit from looking at GrepCode to study how the Java LinkedList iterator implementation works.

Comment: You also did not show how you instantiated your iterator.  This _should_ be an `iterator()` method on your `LinkedList`.  Also, naming your class `LInkedList` is asking for trouble -- that name is already taken for the Java library version, call it something else.

Comment: @JimGarrison The `iterator()` method is simply as is: `return new LinkedListIterator<T>(this);`. I also initially thought the reference to the `LinkedList` (is going to be renamed, thanks for the hint) should be enough. Isn't the `remove()` method from the `LinkedListIterator` then theoretically a copy from the `remove(Object obj)`  in my `LinkedList`?

Comment: @CRoemheld Again: study the Java library implementation to understand how to write this code.  There is too much wrong/missing in your implementation for it to be a quick fix without doing the work for you, which we generally don't do here.